# Android onRestoreInstanceState overwriting values

Tags: android

So I have a weird problem with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState.
The following is what I had up to now, and which was working perfectly. Methods called normally, values saved and restored just fine.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  // Restore value of members from saved state
  mRawImgPath = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH);
  mProImgPath = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  // Save the user's current game state
  savedInstanceState.putString(SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH, mRawImgPath);
  savedInstanceState.putString(SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH, mProImgPath);
}
```

Now I wanted to enhance the code a bit with a third value I wish to save.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  // Restore value of members from saved state
  mRawImgPath = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH);
  mProImgPath = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH);
  mLastState = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  // Save the user's current game state
  savedInstanceState.putString(SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH, mRawImgPath);
  savedInstanceState.putString(SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH, mProImgPath);
  savedInstanceState.putString(SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE, mLastState);
}
```

The methods still get called perfectly but it's not restoring the correct values anymore.
Instead of restoring the correct values into the correct variable, I get `SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE` restored into all three vars (`mRawImgPath`, `mProImgPath` and `mLastState`).

What I can say is, they have the correct value when saving at `onSaveInstanceState()` so they do not have just the wrong value when saving. Also I do not change the values at `onCreate()`, otherwise the first solution (with only two variables) wouldn't work as well.
I have really no idea what's happening there.

If it is of interest, here's the declaration:

```
// Vars
GPSTracker gps;
String mRawImgPath = ""; // Path of the raw image
String mProImgPath = ""; // Path of the processed image
String mLastState = "";

// Save state variables
static final String SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH = "";
static final String SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH = "";
static final String SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE = "";
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static final String SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH = "";
static final String SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH = "";
static final String SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE = "";
```

you have empty names there, change to:

```
static final String SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH = "SAVE_STATE_RAW_IMG_PATH";
static final String SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH = "SAVE_STATE_PRO_IMG_PATH";
static final String SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE = "SAVE_STATE_LAST_STATE";
```

Comment: *Dang* beautiful. It didn't came to my mind that I have to declare the name of the variable as value. Thanks alot.